CS50 SQL - Why does the query for the Moneyball problem 9.sql fail to meet the CS50 check?
I am calculating the average salary paid by Major League Baseball teams in the year 2001. It retrieves data from the salaries table and teams table, joining them based on the team_id. Using AVG(salaries.salary), it computes the average salary for each team, rounding the result to two decimal places with ROUND(..., 2). The WHERE clause filters the results to include only salaries from the year 2001. The GROUP BY clause groups the results by teams.name, ensuring that each row represents a unique team. The results are then sorted in ascending order by "average salary" and limited to the top 5 rows using LIMIT 5. The query effectively identifies and presents the five teams that paid the lowest average salaries in 2001, providing insights into comparative payroll practices within the league during that period.
However I am getting errors no matter how I write my query and the answer does not match.

Please update your question with DDL for the tables, the SQL statement you’ve written and the error messages you are getting - all as editable text appropriately formatted

In addition to the above provide sample test data and expected results. - all as formatted text. See Senseful Solutions for a method to create formatted text - or add a fiddle. Add as an update to the question not as a comment.
